# Needing help with "Misplaced \noalign" as well as \centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

So I'm currently on the task of setting up my first table, to use as preset for future documents. While it works, and gives the result I'd like to see (except for {\centering} not working), it does throw 20 "Misplaced \noalign" errors (Misplaced \noalign. ^^I\end{tabularx})

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}        

    \definecolor{Grey}{gray}{0.8}
    \definecolor{Groy}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{375pt}{lX*{3}{>{\sffamily}rX}X}
        \vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \rowcolor{Grey}\textbf{Land} && \textbf{2002} && \textbf{2001} && \textbf{1990}\\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \cellcolor{Grey}USA && 3 800 000 && 3 778 512 && 3 040 932 \\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \rowcolor{Groy} \cellcolor{Grey}VR China && 1 602 156 && 1 421 268 && 618 000\\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \cellcolor{Grey}Japan && 935 000 && 932 904 && 857 268& \\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \rowcolor{Groy} \cellcolor{Grey}Russland && 888 936 && 888 382 && {\centering}-\\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \cellcolor{Grey}Kanada && 565 000 && 564 108 && 482 028 \\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \rowcolor{Groy} \cellcolor{Grey}Frankreich && 549 245 && 545 000 && 419 219 \\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
        \cellcolor{Grey}Deutschland && 543 561 && 566 835 && 566 484 \\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
            \rowcolor{Groy} \cellcolor{Grey}Weltproduktion && 15 750 000 && 15 684 000 && 11 179 000\\\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This is what it gives out: [image]

So, before I go around using it in something I actually have to turn in, I want it to not throw those errors, or at least understand why they're there... hope you guys can help (and mybe tell me, why centering isn't working?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\vspace` and `\noindent` are wrong in front of `\rowcolor` and also after ``\\``.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have 9 columns declared, and really use only 4 of them?

Answer (score 1):

The tokens `\vspace{2.5pt}\noindent` are completely out of place there.

Here's a realization with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % don't load colortbl after xcolor, use the option

\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{Grey}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{Groy}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  l *{3}{X>{\sffamily}S[table-format=8.0,detect-all]}
}
  \rowcolor{Grey}
\textbf{Land}                  && {\textbf{2002}} && {\textbf{2001}} && {\textbf{1990}}\\
\cellcolor{Grey}USA            &&  3 800 000 &&  3 778 512 &&  3 040 932 \\
  \rowcolor{Groy}
\cellcolor{Grey}VR China       &&  1 602 156 &&  1 421 268 &&    618 000 \\
\cellcolor{Grey}Japan          &&    935 000 &&    932 904 &&    857 268 \\
  \rowcolor{Groy}
\cellcolor{Grey}Russland       &&    888 936 &&    888 382 &&       {--} \\
\cellcolor{Grey}Kanada         &&    565 000 &&    564 108 &&    482 028 \\
  \rowcolor{Groy}
\cellcolor{Grey}Frankreich     &&    549 245 &&    545 000 &&    419 219 \\
\cellcolor{Grey}Deutschland    &&    543 561 &&    566 835 &&    566 484 \\
  \rowcolor{Groy}
\cellcolor{Grey}Weltproduktion && 15 750 000 && 15 684 000 && 11 179 000 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I can see no reason for using sans serif for the data.

In my opinion, the table is better at natural width; in order to try it, replace `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{tabular}`, remove `X` from the specifiers and change `&&` into `&`.

For the following picture I also removed `\sffamily`.

[image]

Comment: the original example has small white spaces between the rows that's most obvious in the first column.  (it looks rather nice to me; maybe the op wants it.  might be good to ask that question.)

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different layout, playing  with the `overhang` parameter of `\columncolor`, still based on `siunitx`. `tabularx` is not needed. Note that, with the `table` option for `xcolor`, you don't have to load `colortbl`. Also, the code is simplified with the `\rowcolors` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\definecolor{Grey}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{Groy}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

{\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}\sisetup{table-format=8.0, detect-family}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{1em}}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{Groy}{}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\columncolor{Grey}[1em][1pt]\cellcolor{Grey}}l*{3}{>{\sffamily}S}}
  \rowcolor{Grey}\textbf{Land} & {\textbf{2002}} & { \textbf{2001}} & {\textbf{1990}} \\
  USA                          & 3 800 000       & 3 778 512        & 3 040 932       \\
  VR China                     & 1 602 156       & 1 421 268        & 618 000         \\
  Japan                        & 935 000         & 932 904          & 857 268         \\
  Russland                     & 888 936         & 888 382          & {---}           \\
  Kanada                       & 565 000         & 564 108          & 482 028         \\
  Frankreich                   & 549 245         & 545 000          & 419 219         \\
  Deutschland                  & 543 561         & 566 835          & 566 484         \\
  Weltproduktion               & 15 750 000      & 15 684 000       & 11 179 000      \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]